# Storing Images in Mongodb With GridFS Using Express Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, multer, gridfs

I am trying to upload, save and display images in MongoDB using express server and GridFS.
Data is sent with FormData with vue.js on the front-end and that part works well.

Images are getting to the server, and it stores that data, but I can not display the uploaded image, instead I get this

[It displays the Image in some encoding I guess.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40ec8.png)

Here is server code for receiving, storing and displaying images.

```
const express = require('express')
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const path = require('path')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const multer = require('multer')
const GridFsStorage = require('multer-gridfs-storage')
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const config = require('../../config/keys')
const morgan = require('morgan')

const images = express()


//  MIDDLEWARE
images.use(methodOverride('_method'))
// images.use(morgan("default"))

//  MONGO URI
const mongoURI = config.dbUrl

//  CREATE MONGO CONNECTION
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI)

//  INITALIZE GRID FS
let gfs

conn.once('open', () => {
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo)
    gfs.collection('uploads')
})

//  CREATING STORAGE ENGINE
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: mongoURI,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const filename = file.originalname
            const fileInfo = {
                filename,
                bucketName: 'uploads'
            }
            resolve(fileInfo)
        })
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage })

//  POST REQUEST UPLOADS FILE TO DATABASE
images.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST REQUEST TO HTTP://LOCALHOST:3000/API/BACKEND/IMAGES/')
    res.json(req.file)
    console.log(req.file)
})

//  GET REQUEST
images.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('GET REQUEST TO HTTP://LOCALHOST:3000/API/BACKEND/IMAGES/')
    const posts = await load();
    res.send(await posts.find({}).toArray())
})

images.get('/:filename', (req, res) => {
    gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename }, (err, file) => {
      // Check if file
      if (!file || file.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({
          err: 'No file exists'
        });
      }
  
      // Check if image
      if (file.contentType === 'image/jpeg' || file.contentType === 'image/png') {
        // Read output to browser
        const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
        readstream.pipe(res);
      } else {
        res.status(404).json({
          err: 'Not an image'
        });
      }
    });
  });


//  LOADING FUNCTION FOR MONGODB
async function load() {
    const client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect
    (`${config.dbUrl}`, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    return client.db('myCluster').collection('uploads.files');
}

module.exports = images
```

Every help would be nice and much appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: You need to set content-type in the response appropriately.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean? Where do i need to change it?